# SQL distinct field combination disregard the position

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I have a SQL question:

Table: Flight

```
Origin  Destination
--------------------
Boston    LA
LA        Bostion
Newyork   LA
DC        Newyork
```

How could I select the distinct combination of the fight path if I do not care origin or destination: (Boston to LA) = (LA to Boston)

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Comment: sql server, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `row_number` to do this. Get the partition by least of origin and destination, greatest of origin and destination so a combination like (a,b),(b,a) is treated the same. Then get the first row per group.

```
select origin,destination from (
select origin,destination
,row_number() over(partition by 
                   case when origin<destination then origin else destination end,
                   case when origin>destination then origin else destination end
                   order by origin) as rnum
from flight
) t
where rnum=1
```

Comment: Are we actually comparing the lengths of columns `origin` and `destination` with each other?

Answer (score 4):

Why isn't this as simple as doing

```
SELECT origin, destination 
FROM flights
UNION -- Will remove duplicates
SELECT destination, origin
FROM flights;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: For some reason this code does not work as expected. I pasted it into this box (already preset by someone else with a different code which I replaced with this one): https://rextester.com/YFZ69961

Answer (score 2):

Does this do what you want?

```
select origin, destination
from flights f
where origin < destination
union all
select destination, origin
from flights f
where origin > destination and
      not exists (select 1
                  from flights f2
                  where f2.destination = f.origin and f2.origin = f.destination
                 );
```

Comment: I don't understand why the "not exist" clause is needed. Would you explain?

Comment: @Nick . . . (1) Otherwise, the query would pick up all rows.  (2) Your data does not have all pairs (if it did, the second subquery would be unnecessary).

Comment: Thanks. I thought replacing 'UNION ALL' with 'UNION" can take care of the duplicates. Wouldn't it?

Comment: @Nick . . . Removing duplicates would typically be much more expensive than `not exists` -- assuming the right indexes exist.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way to find distinct flight routes

```
Select  distinct case when origin < destination then origin else destination end as Distinct_departure,
                case when origin < destination then destination else origin end as Distinct_arrival
From flights
```

Comment: i am not sure , how does it work

Answer (score 1):

Row_Number() would not be correct in case where origin is same for two records but destination is different. In that case, it will be assigned wrong ranks. Better approach would be to use either RANK() or DENSE_RANK() function.

```
select origin,destination from (
select origin,destination
             ,DENSE_RANK() over(partition by 
               case when origin<destination then origin else destination end,
               case when origin>destination then origin else destination end
               order by origin) as rnum
 from flight
 ) t
 where rnum=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT CASE
           WHEN Origin < Destination THEN
               Origin
           ELSE
               Destination
       END AS Terminus1,
       CASE
           WHEN Origin < Destination THEN
               Destination
           ELSE
               Origin
       END AS Terminus2
FROM Flight
GROUP BY Terminus1,
         Terminus2
ORDER BY Terminus1,
         Terminus2;
```

The `CASE`'s are used to sort each record horizontally so that the "lesser" of the two values in each record will be returned first.

`GROUP BY` will then eliminate duplicate records in the horizontally sorted results.

`ORDER BY` isn't required in this case, but I thought it might make the results a bit more readable.  If you are after a set of results that might be processed elsewhere rather than read by a human, you may wish to dump this clause.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct a1.f1,a1.f2 from
(select a.*,row_number() over() rn
from al_ofs_maps.flights a) a1
inner join 
(select a.*,row_number() over() rn
from al_ofs_maps.flights a) a2
on a1.f1=a2.f2 and a1.f2=a2.f1
and a1.rn < a2.rn
union
select distinct  a.*
from al_ofs_maps.flights a
left outer join al_ofs_maps.flights b
on a.f1 = b.f2 and a.f2=b.f1
where b.f1 is null
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation for the code in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest SQL query would be -

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    least(Origin , Destination) AS C1,
    greatest(Origin , Destination) AS C2 
FROM Flight;
```

**Note** - Tested on MySQL

Answer (score 0):

If you run this query on mysql. You will get the records as expected.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
                SELECT LEAST(Origin,Destination),
                       GREATEST( Origin,Destination)
                FROM Flight 
                GROUP BY GREATEST ( Origin,Destination)
    UNION
    SELECT LEAST(Origin,Destination),
                       GREATEST( Origin,Destination)
                FROM Flight 
                GROUP BY LEAST(Origin,Destination)
    )TBL;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM flights 
WHERE origin < destination
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this! works for me:

```
select departure, arrival 
from flight f1, flight f2
where f1.departure != f2.arrival
group by f1.arrival;
```